# Scrollbar on a QTableView does not scroll

Tags: c++, qt, widget, scrollbar, qtableview

My scrollbar on my talbe is visible, but dont scroll , where is my error ?

```
    meineView->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    meineView->setAutoScroll(true);
    meineView->setAutoScrollMargin(20);
    meineView->setHorizontalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerItem);
```

it should be scroll automatically, but should also manually. 
meineView is a QTableView and includes Strings from a dokument or from QTextEditfields. 
I have 2 Buttons, when a pushbutton is clicked, the Strings from the dokument or the textfields was added into the table.

Comment: What class is meineView? Is it QTableView? Or something else? And what is the contents of the view? Does it exceed the scrollable area? Give us more info...

Comment: yes its a QTableView

Comment: I have a custom QTableView class that never does anything with scroll bars in the code and it just works so you sure your not blocking the scroll functionality somehow

Comment: what should blocking it ? i dont can post my full code here.